# Trigger MySql Insert Or Update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need a mysql trigger after insert OR Update a table i want to add to table notifications (and in future send email notifications)

trigger insert work fine
Trigger update have a problem, if I edit "word" he insert correctly, but if I edit again... i receive a error because e try to insert in table notifications the same id

```
    table_real
    -------------
    | id | word | news |
    -------------
    | 1  | this | this |
    -------------
    | 2  | that | this |
    -------------
    | 3  | this | this |
    -------------

    tablenotifications
    ---------------------
    | id | word | news |
    ---------------------
    | 1  | this |   2   |
    ---------------------
    | 2  | that |   1   |


DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_insert` AFTER INSERT
    ON `table_real` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tablenotifications(id, word, news) VALUES (new.id, new.word, new.news);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_update` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `table_real` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO tablenotifications (id, word, news) VALUES (new.id, new.word, new.news);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Solution:
Edit table, change my primary key**

Comment: I guess you should not use `id` as a primary key in `tablenotification` if you want to insert that `id` multiple times into that table, because a primary key `id` for `tablenotification` means you can only insert `id` once to `tablenotification`. Just use another (autoincrement) id as the primary key in that table.

Comment: I change primary key, and problem is solved! thank you

Answer (score 0):

when eciting a table, instead of inserting, update the row that corresponds to the edited id.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `trigger_update` AFTER UPDATE 
ON `table_real` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE  tablenotifications SET id=new.id,  word=new.word, news=new.news;

END$$
```